# Find *.txt files and redirect there content to one file by a separation

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, find

for example:-

```
# ls *.txt
a.txt b.txt c.txt
# cat a.txt
sdfsdfsdf
# cat b.txt
kkmkmmkkmk
# cat c.txt
ererererer
```

I am trying to find all files with *.txt and move there content to another file with separators.

```
# cat output.txt
---------------
sdfsdfsdf
---------------
kkmkmmkkmk
---------------
ererererer
---------------
```

something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for t in *.txt ; do
    cat "$t" >> newfile
    echo '----------------' >> newfile
done
```

Or if you don't want an extra separator after the last file, do this:

```
first=1
for t in *.txt ; do
    if [ "$first" -ne 1 ]; then
        echo '----------------' >> newfile
    fi
    first=0
    cat "$t" >> newfile
done
```

Comment: Thanks Stark, First one is perfect for my condition and Second one is not giving any separator.

Comment: Check the logic of your second implementation, and add double quote to the variable `$t` expansion.

Comment: Logic still wrong: Restore the  `-ne` test you removed and move the `first=0` to the `else` branch.

Comment: I think I'm just not awake.

Answer (score 1):

if you have gawk version 4.++:

```
awk 'BEGINFILE {print "---------------"}1' *.txt
```